# recover a mysql-db from time-machine on a mac

Tags: mysql, timemachine

Somehow the database on my local mac (for testing purposes) got corrupted. So I just took the time-machine backup I had and restored the entire «var»-folder with all the databases, tables and logfiles in it.

But now mysql is acting up and throwing all sorts of errors (tables that are not found, ibd-files corrupted and so on).

How do I restore the databases (creating a mysqldump isn't an option, though).

Comment: What table engines did you use? Mixed MyISAM and InnoDB or only one of them? I'm afraid, in case of InnoDB tables at least, simply copying the table and index files may result in an inconsistent state when restored from there. It is required to shut down the server (called a cold backup) for a guaranteed consistent (and working) backup. [Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-backup.html)

Comment: So which folder did you restore? What type of database is it, INNODB/MYISAM/?

Comment: It's mixed tables (MyISAM and InnoDB) - and I did shut down the server before creating the backup.

Comment: @RiggsFoley: I restored the «var»-Folder, where all the db's and tables are